# The function defined by $f(x)=\sin (\pi x)$ has zeroes at every integer.

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, bisection

The function defined by $f(x)=\sin (\pi x)$ has zeroes at every integer. Show that when $-1<a<0$ and $2<b<3$, the bisection method converges to $0$, if $a+b<2$.

How to approach this? Any ideas?

Comment: You should clarify that $a$ and $b$ are the starting and ending points of the bisection

Comment: Determine if $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are smaller or greater than zero. Then consider the first step in the bisection: $x = \frac{a+b}{2}$. What is the sign of $f(x)$ and based on this what are the new two endpoints now and how many zeros are inside this region?

Answer (score 0):

We have $f (a) < 0, f(b) >0 $.

Also, $-1<a<0$ and $2<b<3$, hence $1< a+b<3$.

If $a+b<2$, then $1<a+b<2$. That is $\frac12 < \frac{a+b}2<1$. Hence $f\left( \frac{a+b}2\right)>0.$

Hence after a single step, the interval to consider is $\left(a, \frac{a+b}2\right)$. Note the function is continuous and the interval end point has opposite signs.

You just have to check that there are no other integers besides $0$ in $\left(a, \frac{a+b}2\right)$.